# Calling a method in ExecuterService using double colon (::)

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, concurrency, executorservice

I have a class constitues 2 methods static and non static respectively, as per my limited knowledge submit method accepts runnable,callable instance directly or through lamba expression.

Today I came to know that we can even call or trigger static as well as non static method directly by using double colon which has been added in java 8.

I was just wondering how this works, there is no run method in my class and it doesn't implements runnable and even I'm not using lamba?

Is it a good practice to use :: or one should pass the runnable or callable instance.

Is there any other way to call a method inside submit() rather passing an instance?

```
Class A {

public static void printSomething(){
System.out.println("Staitc Method");
}

public void print()
{
System.out.println("Non-Staitc Method");
}

}

psvm()
{
A a = new A():
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
es.submit(A::printSomething);  //Expected is runnable or callable task
es.submit(a::print);
}
```

Comment: You can        `es.submit(() ->
        { // code/invoke a void method here
        });`. The `run` method invokes your `print` methods.

Comment: @Naman this is lambda expression which works, indirectly it is run method, but how :: works?

Comment: The linked question answers that nicely with varied examples in different answers.

Answer (score 3):

`A::printSomething` is called a method reference. When you use a method reference in a place that expects an interface like Runnable or Callable, Java automatically creates an implementation of that interface that calls the method.

That is,

```
es.submit(A::printSomething);
```

behaves the same as

```
es.submit(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        A.printSomething();
    }
});
```

but is easier to read and does not create a new class everywhere you use it, or a new object instance every time it's called.

You can read more about method references in

- The [tutorial from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)
- [This write-up on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-references)

Another way of achieving the same is using *lambda expressions* such as:

```
es.submit(() -> A.printSomething());
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `Runnable` is a [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html), you can use lambda expressions or method references that fit it even if the method name doesn't match. Therefore any no-arg void method can be used as a `Runnable`.

```
Runnable r1 = () -> a.printSomething();
Runnable r2 = A::printSomething();  // Method reference, short-hand
Runnable r3 = () -> A.printSomething(); // Same as r2, but as explicit lambda expression
```

Comment: Yep, the key term being the "functional interface" 1+

Comment: Does using method reference each time for different methods is a good practice?

Comment: @Shelly I guess that depends on who you ask. It doesn't make much of a difference for parameterless methods, but when the method has parameters it can become clearer to use the explicit version `(a, b) -> foo(a, b)` vs. `this::foo`, for example when using Streams.

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the method reference works even though the class does not implement a `void run()` method is because what matters for Functional Interface assignment is the method signature and not the method names.

The method signature of `A`'s `printSomething` matches `Runnable`'s `run` and for that reason it works. Notice this only works with Functional Interfaces (i.e. those with only one method, said method method not having a default implementation).

Is it good practice? It's a matter of style but it is definitely not bad practice to use method references, and they're also more concise than `left -> right` lambdas.

I suggest you try this out yourself so you're clear on the rules.

```
public class FunctionalInterfaceDemo {

  public static class SimpleClass {
    public static void doItStatic() {
    }

    public void doItNonStatic() {
    }
  }

  interface MyOwnFunctionalInterface {
    void methodA();
  }

  interface NotAFunctionalInterface {
    void methodA();

    void methodB();
  }

  interface AlsoNotAFunctionalInterface {
    default void methodA() {
    }
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyOwnFunctionalInterface compiles = SimpleClass::doItStatic;
    MyOwnFunctionalInterface alsoCompiles = new SimpleClass()::doItNonStatic;
    NotAFunctionalInterface doesNotCompile = SimpleClass::doItStatic;
    AlsoNotAFunctionalInterface alsoDoesNotCompile = SimpleClass::doItStatic;
  }
```

}

Comment: You example is really helpfull